# Skip adding element when 'let' can't be counted within lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following lambda expression:

```
string queryToken = queryTokens.Last();
var result = from locationAddress in locations
             let tokens = GetLetterTokens(locationAddress.Name)
             let distance = (from token in tokens
                             where token.Contains(queryToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                             select token.Length - queryToken.Length).Min()
             orderby distance
             select new
                        {
                            LocationAddress = locationAddress,
                            LocationDistance = distance,
                        };
```

It doesn't matter what it's written for. Sometimes when counting `distance`, there are no `tokens` containing `queryToken`, so `.Min()` couldn't be returned. How to skip these cases? I don't want to add them into `result` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
let tokens = ...
where tokens.Any(token.Contains(queryToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
let distance = ...
```

Alternatively, just filter when you select the tokens, and then check whether any exist:

```
var result = from locationAddress in locations
             let tokens = GetLetterTokens(locationAddress.Name)
                              .Where(token => token.Contains(queryToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             where tokens.Any()
             let distance = tokens.Min(token => token.Length - queryToken.Length)
```